# Assign a type of a method to property of the parent object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say that we have below situation:

```
class SomeClass {
    public someProperty;

    public someMethodA(): void {
         this.someProperty = this.someMethodB()
    }

    public someMethodB() {
        ...some code...
    }
}
```

I want *someProperty*'s type to be same as the type returned by *someMethodB*. i.e. if *someMethodB* returns number, then *someProperty*'s type should be a number as well.
If somebody will change *someMethodB* later, in a way that will change the type of value that's being returned, then the type of *someProperty* should change as well automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookup type `SomeClass["someMethodB"]` to reference the type of the method and the `ReturnType` built-in type alias to extract the return type:

```
public someProperty: ReturnType<SomeClass["someMethodB"]>;
```